# Imgur как постоянный хостинг изображений

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-служба, хостинг-изображений

Встал вопрос хранения изображений для сайта. Изображения - основной контент, но заливаться будут мной.
Посмотрел из множества, но заинтересовал imgur. Так что есть пара вопросов по нему, ответы на которые в справке не нашел.
Какова продолжительность рабочей жизни ссылки на изображение?
Будет ли ссылка видоизменяться со временем? Бывало ли такое, как недавно в гугл фото у многих сменился юрл к картинкам?

Answer (score 1):

> Какова продолжительность рабочей жизни ссылки на изображение?

[Бессрочно](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920111904/https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/201476457-How-long-do-you-keep-the-images-). Изображения удаляются только по запросам правообладателей, правительства и т.п.

> Будет ли ссылка видоизменяться со временем? Бывало ли такое, как недавно в гугл фото у многих сменился юрл к картинкам?

На моей памяти такого не было. Я думаю, если они и будут изменять ссылки, то сделают всё как нормальные люди — через 301 редирект. Все таки Imgur создан для того, чтобы делиться картинками на сайтах, а Google Photos — что-то вроде облачного хранилища фотографий.

Да и не стали бы они предоставлять API, особенно на коммерческой основе, если бы картинки со временем удалялись. Stack Exchange, например, использует Imgur в качестве хостинга изображений.

Comment: Я уже часа 2 гуглю разное и вроде как нарыл, что хранение бессрочно (правда смущает короткая ссылка, типа такой: http://imgur.com/CkU8Q79). И ещё встречал, что если не пользоваться аккаунтом 6 месяцев, то он автоматом удаляется вместе со всеми фотками, но ссылку на этот пост всё найти не могу.

Comment: @VostokSisters, это обычная перма-ссылка, ведущая на пост. Соответственно, если в начале добавить `i.`, а в конце — `.jpg`, то получится ссылка на само изображение: [i.imgur.com/CkU8Q79.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/CkU8Q79.jpg)

Comment: Да, но ссылка всё равно слишком (подозрительно вернее) короткая... Или это нормально?

Comment: @VostokSisters, да ничего подозрительного. Обычные короткие ссылки. Всегда такие были. А если восьсимвольные комбинации закончатся, то просто расширят новым картинкам выборку до 9 символов. Обычная практика.

Comment: Я к тому, что за такое время ещё не закончились? :D

Comment: Нашел [информацию](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/203887085-Inactive-Account-Policy-)  по поводу инактива. Если не заходить на имгур год,  то бесконечное хранение изображения резко становится становится  конечным.

Comment: @VostokSisters, там ни слова о том, что картинки удалятся. Я думаю, более точный ответ вам даст поддержка Imgur.

Comment: я уже им об этом написал)

Answer (score 0):

Правила Imgur [прямо запрещают такое использование](https://imgur.com/tos):

> Also, don't use Imgur to host image libraries you link to from elsewhere, content for your website, advertising, avatars, or anything else that turns us into your content delivery network.

За нарушение этого правила грозит бан и удаление всех картинок. [Ещё одно подтверждение.](https://community.imgur.com/t/what-do-the-tos-mean-by-dont-use-imgur-to-host-image-libraries-you-link-to-from-elsewhere/21348/2)

Не будьте жадиной, подключите себе S3 или какой-нибудь из множества их аналогов.

Comment: Забавно, что я использую имгур именно для этого лет шесть, а ни одна картинка так и не пропала)

Comment: На каком сайте, покажете? Поправим.

Comment: Слишком много мелких разных и не обязательно моих, чтобы показать их все) У̶ ̶S̶t̶a̶c̶k̶O̶v̶e̶r̶f̶l̶o̶w̶ ̶т̶о̶ж̶е̶ ̶а̶в̶а̶т̶а̶р̶к̶и̶ ̶н̶а̶ ̶и̶м̶г̶у̶р̶е̶

Comment: SO под исключение попадает. Так же как и, например, картинки в постах на форумах.